# IF statement with javascript promise .then()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, axios

I am playing around with React recently. I have a axios post function in my callback function.

I am able to get my data from promise then(). My code is something like below:

```
export const upload = (user, history) => async dispatch => {
const { fileBase } = user;

getBase64(user.fileBase, function (result) {
    const query = `query{test( test:"test") { success }}`;
    const finalQuery = JSON.stringify(getBody(query, { ip: result }));})))
    getRes(finalQuery, function (res) {
        res.then(function (result) {
            // i am able to access the data through console.dir(result.data.data)
            // when i using code below it hits error
            // if(result.data.data.login.success) -> it return to me the data is null, even the console.dir is null too.
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("err: " + err);
        }); 
     });
   });
};
function getRes(finalquery, cb) {
console.log("finalquery: " + finalquery);
cb(axios.post(API_URL, finalquery));
}
```

Picture below is my object structure from promise.

[image]

I have gone through a lot of reference through only, but I do not see anyone having if statement by checking the result data from promise.

Is it possible for me to check the promise data value and do something in promise then()? if yes, how? if no, why and how?

Comment: Can you share where and how you are calling `getRes` ?

Comment: hi @HarkiratSaluja i have edited my question with more code.

Comment: This seems fine to me and should work, How is your result object structured? It might be possible that you are trying to access something that does not exist.

Comment: It weird that, everything was find if i use console.dir, i was able to get my desire result. The error will come when I use neither console.log nor if(the object value)

Comment: code looks correct. Can you please share the structure of result object?

Comment: updated. it weird that if i access with IF statement and console.log then even console.dir will become null. but if I use only console.dir then the result is accessible

Comment: `getRes` really should **`return`** that promise instead of calling a callback with a promise as an argument

Comment: @Bergi yes. it working. thx. put it as answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @DaveCruise I don't see how that changes anything about your problem with `result.data` so I don't think it's an answer